# pylibjpeg-libjpeg is not installed

Tags: python, pyinstaller, libjpeg

I have a program based on python 3 to read dicom images. it has GUI design by pyqt5 for users that open and select images.
the program works perfectly fine but when I made onefile (.exe) through pyinstaller, it does not show the image and display this error :
"Unable to convert the Pixel Data as the 'pylibjpeg-libjpeg' plugin is not installed"

pylibjpeg-libjpeg was installed and I imported to the program.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

For plugins that are imported through pkg_resources, pyinstaller is not able to freeze it and thus can't load at run time.
So to make it freeze the plugins we need to create run-time hooks, I found this [link](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3050) and followed the hook file creation and it seems to have resolved this issue.